# Free video converter where I can choose video/audio codec?

Tags: video, encoding

I'm looking for free (or < 10$) video converter on mac with following features:

Another features which are welcome:

- option to choose file format (.mpg, .avi etc)
- option to choose video/audio encoding (xvid, h264, acc etc)
- option to always save output to the same directory the source is in
- batch processing of many files
- possibility to set created/modified time of created file to the same as source has

Comment: If command line does not scare you I recommend ffmpeg (I installed mine as ffmpeg + nonfree with MacPorts).  Works.  Always.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked out [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr)? Looks to have what you are looking for...

Comment: Looks quite good, but are there only MP4 and MKV output formats available?

Comment: Apparently those are the only available output formats - check https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/Containers

Comment: Well, that'll do. However, I'd love an app where I could drag&drop files (sometimes there are quite many of them) and that has option to output to the same dir where source is.

Answer (score 1):

[image: VLC exporting]

Free and OpenSource [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) supports video encoding

Answer (score 1):

[Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/):

Convert almost any video to MP4, WebM (vp8), Ogg Theora, or for Android, iPhone, and iPad. Batch conversion, custom sizing, and more.

Available for Linux, OS X & Windows